# How to prevent recreation of a singleTask activity on back button press?

Tags: android, android-launcher, launchmode

I have a simple launcher app, that doesn't launch any apps, just shows a WebView. It is set as the default launcher. I don't use any other apps on this tablet. When I restart the tablet, this launcher starts as expected. My problem is if I press the back button of the device, the activity is destroyed, and it is created again as a new activity. I don't get what's the point of this behaviour, as the activity is already visible... The view's launch mode is singleTask, so I expect  it to just simply stay where it is, rather than being recreated. How can this be done? As far as I understand the documentation, this should work as I expect it, instead of the way it does now.

> The system creates the activity at the root of a new task and routes
>   the intent to it. **However, if an instance of the activity already
>   exists, the system routes the intent to existing instance through a
>   call to its onNewIntent() method, rather than creating a new one.**
>   http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

Comment: Can't you just override onBackPressed() ?

Comment: I'll accept this if you add it as an answer. Simple solution, works perfectly now.

Comment: Okay, I'll add it as answer then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override onBackPressed() and do nothing like

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() { }
```

Comment: I've read somewehere that moveTaskToBack(true); should be used, but it work's perfectly without that, so I use your solution, it's cleaner.